# How can I control fan speed easily?

Tags: cpu, overheating, fan, temperature

I have a PC which overheats and shuts down without warning.
I installed `lm-controls` and `fancontrol`.
I ran sensors detect and said yes to all questions. 
I typed

```
sudo service kmod start
```

When I try `pwmconfig`, I get

```
There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

When I typed `sensors`, I saw the CPU was already over 80 Celsius. So I turned it off.

```
sensors: 
coretemp-isa-0000 
Adapter:ISA adapter 
Core 0:   + 84.0°C (high = +80.0C, crit = +90.0C) 
Core 1:   + 82.0°C (high = +80.0C, crit = +90.0C)
```

After this, I got lost. I found instructions about how to configure the PC so that such a temperature triggers such and such an action, but this is not really what I want: too complicated.

I would like a way to set up all fans at maximum speed, and I don't mind having to type this command each time I turn on this machine. Never mind the temperature, turn them on at full speed from the moment the PC starts working, then maybe it will stay on a little longer...

For the moment, it crashes after half an hour, or one hour, depending upon what I'm doing.

To manage `do-release-upgrade`, I had to bring the pc outside when the temperature was around zero. What shall I do during summer?

Comment: Try to clean the air intake and outlet with a vacuum cleaner, and if it is a stationary PC, open it up and carefully clean out the dust from the inside. Often old computers have build up an amazing amount of dust and dirt, blocking efficient air flow. Also check if the powersupply- and CPU fan (if any) runs as expected. Replace cpu-fan if defective.

Comment: Thanks karel, but pwmconfig does not function for me. I read "man fancontrol" but I still haven't found the configuration file they mention.

Comment: @Soren A : I can hear a fan. How do I find out if it is the CPU fan or another one? Cleaning it, I have already tried. Even running it without the keyboard (plugging in a usb keyboard) to let it more open to air...

Comment: Usually, the computer / bios should manage the fans correctly on its own without needing to to override this in software - I'd also suggest cleaning out the dust. Also, what specific computer is it ? The way to control fan speed on Sony laptops is different to Dell laptops or desktop machines, for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I debug an overheating problem on a Dell Inspiron 1564?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9820/how-do-i-debug-an-overheating-problem-on-a-dell-inspiron-1564) and [Fan control on MSI laptop: no pwm-capable sensors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783069/fan-control-on-msi-laptop-no-pwm-capable-sensors)

Comment: Thank you again karel, this last link I hadn't read. But... Updating the BIOS? How could I update the BIOS, the pc only goes online after the OS has loaded...?